# Pasting data in multiple text boxes

Tags: google-chrome, data-entry

So I have a zero-reporting data entry task which I do monthly. For a couple of cells, I have to enter zero manually ([as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t5JV.png)), which is very much frustrating.

Is there any web add-on I could use to paste zero in multiple cells at once?

Comment: Seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers only select text.

No way to select input-boxes (at least not yet).

I know what you are thinking.. Excel!  Or Spreadsheets.

So.. unless the web-application you use, is rewritten to "mimic" spreadsheets (just like Google Sheets runs within the browser 100%).. 
.. can't give you any hope.